# How can i recover files from hdd dedicated to unbootable OS with Ubuntu on USB?

Tags: boot, windows, hard-drive, live-usb

I am using Ubuntu on a USB, and i want to recover the data from my hdd because Windows wont boot.

I am new to Ubuntu and don't want to screw up the data on my hard drive.

back story:
I installed Ubuntu because after installing window's 10, i was unable to log into my computer, so i tried reverting back to Window's 8 to reinstall and try again.  It then got caught in cycle of trying to revert back to the previous build, then shutting off, turning on, trying to revert, then shutting off, and turning on and so forth... basically, i am in limbo between two OS's, so in have Ubuntu on a USB to try to recover the data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Setting the boot priorities in BIOS and putting your USB containing Ubuntu before the HDD with windows will boot up Ubuntu and you will have the HDD mounted as a storage device.

Comment: I put the USB ubuntu first of the boot priorities list, but it did not solve the problem.  i still am unable to mount the HDD.  i ran sudo fdisk -l and the output  says the "Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary." and that GPT was detected, which is not supported.  what do i do?